How do I actually automate with PowerQuery?
I had been under the impression that one of the key features of Excel's PowerQuery add-in was the ability to automate/reuse repetitive processes. I thought this would be achieved extracting the steps, but according to the internet, the solution is to copy the code from the Advanced Editor and paste it in the new query, and while that's way better than redoing all the steps manually, it's still far from ideal.
Concretely, every 1st of each month I receive new PDF files. These files will be added to a specific folder after the PDF files from the previous month have been deleted, replacing them.
The data of the PDF files is then extracted and cleaned using PowerQuery, and then further worked on with VBA, and in the end printed, and all that month's data and files can then be deleted.
The files are all formatted the same, the only thing changing being the data in them.
Ideally, what I'm trying to achieve is to automate this process as much as possible, as the steps every month are always the exact same.
In other words: I open the specific folder, I delete the existing files and drag the new ones, and then upon opening Excel/PowerBI, I run all the steps needed to extract, clean and load this new data the exact same way I did the previous month. Once I have that, it's easy to let VBA take over the rest.
I'm positive that something like this is possible, but despite my best efforts I'm having trouble understanding Excel's features such as Connections and Data Refreshing and whether/how can they can be helpful and to what extent.

Trying to directly answer what I think is your question: since your pulling data from a pdf file understanding data connections is not necessary. Just make sure the new pdf file is the same name as the old one. You should then be able to use the same excel file (that has the power query 'steps") and go on the table created by power query and right-click refresh. The table should update with the values from the new pdf. You can then finish up with your VBA script.

copy/paste from/to the advance editor is only needed if you are transferring the steps to a new excel file. As you learn more you'll find you can incorporate the power query part into your VBA script too.

Sounds like Data > Refresh All is what you need to pull the new data from the new files, then run your VBA. Or incorporate the refresh into the VBA if that works better for you, as suggested by some answers

You can use VBA to automate the refreshing of tables using Power Query, the method is: QueryTable.Refresh.  Here's an example of the syntax
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("myworksheetname").ListObjects("mytablename").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

The BackgroundQuery parameter is important - without that your macro will continue through other steps while the Power Query is still being refreshed.
Here's the official documentation, FWIW:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.refresh
IMO it is too focussed on SQL scenarios.
